# spring data jpa filter children in @OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have a **EmployeeTest** entity which is parent and **FunGroupInfo** entity which is child. both these two entities are **mapped by employeeId**. I need a way to filter out the child entities which matches the search condition, so that the result will contain only parent and child(which meets requirement).

EmployeeTest class:

```
@Entity(name = "EmployeeTbl")
public class EmployeeTest{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "emp_id")
 private String employeeId;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy= "employeeId", fetch =FetchType.Eager)
 private Set<FunGroupInfo> funGroupInfo;
}
```

FunGroupInfo class:

```
@Entity(name = "FunGroupTbl")
public class FunGroupInfo{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "group_id")
 private String groupId;

 @Column(name = "emp_id")
 private String employeeId;

 @Column(name = "type_id")
 private String typeId;

 @Column(name = "active")
 private String activeFlag;

}
```

EmpRepository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeTest, String>{
List<EmployeeTest> findByFunGroupInfoTypeId(String typeId)
}

//inside by test method

@Autowired 
private EmpRepository  empRepository;

List<EmployeeTest> empList = empRepository.findByFunGroupInfoTypeId("2");
```

Above line returns me List with FunGroupInfo where typeId are in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but i need to get the only the matching FunGroupInfo with typeId 2 info

Result which i get now [image: Result which i get now] but i actually need only the highlighted one along with parent

Comment: You can't do that. The association represents the mapping between an EmployeeTest and its fundGroupInfo. All of them. Always. If you want an EmployeeTest and only some of its fundGroupInfos, then use a query such as `select testEmployee, fundGroupInfo from ... where...`, and get the fundGroupInfo from the second element of each returned array.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using *Hibernate*, you can use the annotation *@Where* to filter elements on the *OneToMany* relationship.

Example:

```
  import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
  ...
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employeeId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Where(clause = "type_id = '2'")
  private Set<FunGroupInfo> funGroupInfo;
  ...
```

More information can be consulted [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-filter-entities-mapped-association/).