# Spring Data findAll with filtered nested objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am currently developing a Spring Boot 2.5.5 app which needs to integrate some games. Each `Game` entity contains multiple `GameProfile` entities. Since the app and games are multilingual, we store all the generic fields in the `GameProfile` entity and all the others which are tied to the current language, are stored in an extra relation called `GameProfileTranslation` which references a `Language` entity.

Following are the three entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAME_PROFILE")
@Getter
@Setter
public class GameProfile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GAME_PROFILE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "game_profile_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "game_profile_seq", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName="game_profile_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE")
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GAME_ID")
    private Game game;

    @Column(name = "DIFFICULTY")
    private GameDifficulty difficulty;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gameProfile", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<GameProfileTranslation> translations = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAME_PROFILE_TRANSLATION")
@Getter
@Setter
public class GameProfileTranslation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GAME_PROFILE_TRANSLATION_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "game_profile_translation_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "game_profile_translation_seq", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName="game_profile_translation_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GAME_PROFILE_ID")
    private GameProfile gameProfile;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    private Language language;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Language {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "language", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "language", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<GameProfileTranslation> gameProfileTranslations = new HashSet<>();

}
```

For the past two days I have been trying to create a repository method which returns all the `GameProfile` entities based on a `languageId` and a `gameId` given as `@RequestParam` to my Controller. To be more precise, I want to find all the `GameProfiles` and filter the nested `translations` object based on the language given.

I have tried two approaches, which are presented below. Both of these methods actually return all the `GameProfile` entities but the nested `translations` object contains all the `GameProfileTranslation` entities in the database. It is like the `translations` cannot be filtered by the language.

If I copy & paste the native query below in a Query Tool in pgAdmin I get the result I desire. However, using it through Spring Data returns all the translations.

My two approaches:

```
    @Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT * " +
                "FROM game_profile AS gp " +
                " INNER JOIN game_profile_translation AS gpt ON gp.game_profile_id = gpt.game_profile_id " +
                " INNER JOIN language AS l ON gpt.language_id = l.language_id " +
                "WHERE l.language_id = :languageId AND gp.game_id = :gameId ")
    List<GameProfile> findAllByGameIdAndLanguageId(@Param("gameId") Long gameId, @Param("languageId") Long languageId);
```

and

```
    @Query(value =  "SELECT gp " +
                    "FROM GameProfile AS gp JOIN FETCH gp.translations AS gpt " +
                    "WHERE gp.game.id = :gameId AND gpt.language.id = :languageId ")
    List<GameProfile> findAllByGameIdAndLanguageId(@Param("gameId") Long gameId, @Param("languageId") Long languageId);
```

TLDR: Both of these methods return all the `GameProfile` entites without filtering the nested `translations` object. To be more exact, the `translations` field contains all the translations available in the database regardless of the `languageId`.

Is there a way to return a `List<GameProfile>` entities with the `translations` object filtered by the `languageId`?

What I have tried:

1. [Filter child object in Spring Data Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684361/filter-child-object-in-spring-data-query)
2. [Filtering out nested objects in JPA query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266634/filtering-out-nested-objects-in-jpa-query)
3. [Filter child object in Spring Data Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684361/filter-child-object-in-spring-data-query)

Comment: That's not supported, your could remove the `private Set<GameProfileTranslation> translations` association, make it `@Transient` and fetch it separately. Alternatively since you have `@ManyToOne` on `GameProfile` in `GameProfileTranslation` you can just fetch that entity instead and construct the dto from there.

Look at similar answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919686/annotation-to-filter-results-of-a-onetomany-association  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025040/spring-data-jpa-filter-children-in-onetomany

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring data jpa filter children in @OneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025040/spring-data-jpa-filter-children-in-onetomany)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but it seemed strange to me that you can't do it through Spring. Thanks for your help.